# How to fetch API with a 0 in the JSON

Tags: reactjs, api

I am trying to fetch an API in React.JS with different data on it. However I am unable to fetch anything that has a number in it.

[image]

For example I am able to fetch the temperature in an API by doing data.main.temp or the humidity by doing data.main.humidity. How can I do the same for weather.0.description, since instead I get errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick `weather[0].description` (Get value relevant to 0th index of the array)

Answer (score 0):

Use `weather[0].id` or `weather[0].main`